# Tweaking YouTube playback

Tags: youtube, html5, flash

How can I adjust brightness and speed while watching a video on YouTube?

If there isn't a way to do this with YouTube's Flash Player, can I do this with HTML5 video (through [their beta](http://www.youtube.com/html5))?

Comment: Youtube's HTML5 player provides an option at the base of the video to adjust playback speed. See: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9948/speed-up-youtube-playback/9951#9951

Comment: Already answered (for speed): http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54506/20552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube does not offer brightness/speed controls. It might be possible for a website programmer to implement such controls with HTML5, but youtube has not done so. I would recommend adjusting brightness on your monitor, or downloading the video and playing it back with a local media player program with such controls.