# Playing YouTube videos at half speed?

Tags: youtube, video

Is there a way to play a YouTube video at half the speed (like what we can do in [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player)?)

I'm looking for a free solution if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube's video player has no native feature to change playback speed. However, there is a shareware app which lets you change the speed of videos played on online players: [MySpeed!](http://www.enounce.com/)

> Online video is everywhere – lectures, labs, tutorials, certification
>   courses, seminars, news, sports and, of course, YouTube! MySpeed from
>   Enounce lets you change the playback speed of Flash video without any
>   loss of audio quality. (No chipmunk sound.) It’s like speed-reading
>   for video! If your Windows PC or Mac can view videos on YouTube,
>   MySpeed will work!

Comment: btw what does a chipmunk sound mean ?

Comment: I think it's some kind of chittering (high-pitched) sound, probably a simile for generated bad sound.

Comment: Remember Alvin and the Chipmunks? Watch a trailer to find out.. http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi984744217/

Answer (score 7):

If you use a HTML5 compatible browser, you can play videos at 1/2 or 1/4 playback speed using the [YouTube HTML5 player](http://www.quora.com/YouTube/How-do-you-slow-down-YouTube-videos/answer/Brian-Yee).

You can visit http://www.youtube.com/html5 to join the beta or add &html5=1 to any video.

Comment: It is possible to play YouTube videos at custom speed by running this in a developer console while a web page with a YouTube video is open -
document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = 3  http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78669/2356

Answer (score 3):

You can speed `down` at half speed or speed `up` YouTube videos. Here's how: [Speed up YouTube Playback?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9948/speed-up-youtube-playback/54506#54506)

Comment: My computer seems to hang when I hit the `Play` button....

Comment: It worked fine for me in my old Core2Duo/Win7 laptop. I tested this with multiple videos.

Answer (score 1):

[AnyVideoConverter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/) will do a direct download from YouTube for you and convert to the format of your choice.  It's free and good.  Obviously not a solution within the browser but I didn't read that was a requirement for you.

Comment: If the YouTube video has been downloaded (usually as a Flash video) then the conversion step is not necessary. It can be played in VLC Player as is (at half the speed).