# Play YouTube videos at speeds OTHER THAN 0.25, 0.5, Normal, 1.25, 1.5, or 2

Tags: youtube

Other than downloading the video and playing it on my own VLC player or whatever, is there a way I can play YouTube videos at other speeds? (E.g. 2.1, 2.2, ... , 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, ... 4.0)

If it matters, I'm using Windows 8, PC, Chrome.

[I don't think this is a duplicate.]

Answer (score 3):

This code entered into the console will work:
`document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = 0.3;`

This sets it to .3x the normal speed.

Comment: Thank you very much